# Model saving and manipulation in the view for 2 model lists

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a MVC Model that will have 2 lists as well as some other properties. List 1 is a check box list. List 2 is a list of start and end times. I have these set up and working but now I need to be able to put more data into list 2 which I have achieved with Jquery but adding in javascript. This does not add it to the model data. I then need to post both of these lists to a controller action so that I can loop them and post them into the database(not my issue). I need to fill the models to be sent. I am unsure how to get that in and am drawing a blank on filling the second model using jquery/js.

I could do this in single entries rather easily but I want to be able to submit more than one at a time.

I have tried creating a partial view with just the model list data in it which presents but then I have the same problem with filling the model. I have tried just doing it through MVC but I am not saving as I go I want the customer to be able to put in a few changes and then save. So it has to be saved on the DOM and I am using a table for that. I want that table to be model data.

model

```
public List<PersonelList _ViewModel> PersonelList { get; set; }
public List<OutTimesForList_ViewModel> OutTimesList { get; set; }

public DateTime? StartDateTime { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndDateTime { get; set; }
```

They are nullable (datetimes) because of a JS datetime picker I am using shows a time in the textbox already if I dont send it nullable.

In the view they would enter a start time and end time hit add then I want it to be added to the OutTimesList so that the post would give me that data filled in the model list. The personelList is the CB list for times that will be added, so if checked then add these times.

When a post is done both lists would be sent to the controller for me to traverse and submit data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery ajax post with [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). With collection of object it should look like this:

```
$( "#YourFormId" ).submit(function(event) {
var formData = new FormData($("#YourFormId"))

//todo need to get properties of PersonelList and OutTimesList via jquery

var indexPersonelList = 0;
for(var pair of PersonelList){
    var item = pair[key];
    formData.append("PersonelList[" + indexPersonelList + "].Id", item.Id);
    indexPersonelList++;
}

var indexOutTimesList = 0;
for(var pair of OutTimesList){
    var item = pair[key];
    formData.append("OutTimesList[" + indexOutTimesList + "].Id", item.Id);
    indexOutTimesList++;
}

$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/MyController/MyAction',
       data: formData,

       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function (data) {
            //some success stuff
       },
       error: function (error) {
            //some error stuff
       }
      }); 
});
```